# make this sum using only +

Tags: calculation-puzzle, formation-of-numbers

A bit of a speed question this, first correct answer gets the check. Although you are allowed to use computers, it might be quicker not to.
By placing only $+$ signs between some of the numbers on the left hand side, make this expression true:

> $1\;\;2\;\;3\;\;4\;\;5\;\;6\;\;7\;\;8\;\;9 = 855$

For example if we had $1\;\;2\;\;3\;\;4 = 19$, the answer is $12+3+4=19$

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It is

> $1 + 2 +3 + 54 + 6 + 789 = 855$

---

**Edit**

Nevermind, it is

> $12 + 3 + 45 + 6 + 789 = 855$

and it could also be

> $123 + 45 + 678 + 9 = 855$

Comment: no because you've got 54 not 45

Comment: @JonMarkPerry oh nevermind, thought I could do that :D

Comment: @JonMarkPerry updated solution

Comment: correct but not the one I've got

Comment: @JonMarkPerry another solution added :D

Comment: bingo! and I thought it would be unique!

Answer (score 5):

It can be-

> $1+2+3+4+56+789=855$

Comment: correct but not the one I've got

Comment: it seems there can be multiple acceptable solution within given constraints.

Comment: That's what I got too :)